# Gedit syntax highlighting not working

Tags: linux, syntax, highlighting, opensuse, gedit

I have been using gedit for most of my C++ as well as php editing for a couple of months with syntax highlighting working fine. Just recently I went to view one of my .cpp files and the Syntax Highlighting failed. I tried multiple other files and now syntax highlighting fails for all of them. I receive the following errors when gedit runs:

```
(gedit:9833): GLib-CRITICAL **: PCRE library is compiled without UTF8 support

(gedit:9833): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_regex_match_full: assertion `regex != NULL' failed

(gedit:9833): GLib-CRITICAL **: PCRE library is compiled without UTF8 support

(gedit:9833): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_regex_replace_eval: assertion `regex != NULL' failed

(gedit:9833): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_regex_unref: assertion `regex != NULL' failed

(gedit:9833): GLib-CRITICAL **: PCRE library is compiled without UTF8 support

(gedit:9833): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_regex_match_full: assertion `regex != NULL' failed

(gedit:9833): GLib-CRITICAL **: PCRE library is compiled without UTF8 support

(gedit:9833): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_regex_replace_eval: assertion `regex != NULL' failed

(gedit:9833): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_regex_unref: assertion `regex != NULL' failed

(gedit:9833): GLib-CRITICAL **: PCRE library is compiled without UTF8 support

(gedit:9833): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_regex_match_full: assertion `regex != NULL' failed

(gedit:9833): GLib-CRITICAL **: PCRE library is compiled without UTF8 support

(gedit:9833): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_regex_replace_eval: assertion `regex != NULL' failed

(gedit:9833): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_regex_unref: assertion `regex != NULL' failed

(gedit:9833): GtkSourceView-WARNING **: in file /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/cpp.lang: style 'c:keyword' not defined

(gedit:9833): GtkSourceView-WARNING **: Failed to load '/usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/cpp.lang': style override used with wildcard context reference in language 'cpp' in ref 'def:line-continue'
```

This is a really frustrating issue that just started happening recently and I'm not sure why.

Additional Info:

- I don't have root access
- My machine is running openSUSE 11.3
- gedit version: 2.28.3
- pcretest command returns: PCRE version 7.6 2008-01-28
- I have rebooted multiple times hoping this would fix itself, but no luck

I would greatly appreciate any help or ideas on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out my issue after a lot of messing around with it. I was working with programs that involved editing my LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, so I added a couple lines into my .cshrc to add append a few shared libraries. I made to sure to append my newly added libraries to the variable but for whatever reason this still messed up Gedit's ability to do syntax highlighting. After taking the setenv commands out of my .cshrc script, I rebooted and Gedit's syntax highlighting was back to normal.

I've heard using LD_LIBRARY_PATH was considered bad practice. Now I have first-hand experience on what can go wrong.